# Why did Aqua/Ruby's name not change when Ai died?

Tags: oshi-no-ko

In the story *Oshi no Ko*, Hoshino Ai, who was a famous idol, died. After she died her son and daughter Hoshino Ruby and Hoshino Aquamarine were left to their mother's boss. Normally in these situation doesn't their name change? Why are they still called Hoshino and how did no one care when their name was Hoshino like Ai?

Answer (score 5):

I can't answer anything about how "moving family register" didn't change the twins' names, or if this would even be expected under Japanese law, but to answer your question about how it pertains to hiding their parentage:

## It's *Ai* whose family name is secret.

> Ai's last name was never made public.

-- Kurokawa Akane, chapter 51

There was never a celebrity "Hoshino Ai", only "B-Komachi's Ai". Although this is only directly stated once, textual support throughout the manga is consistent:

In chapter 1/episode 1, Gorou, a diehard fan for four years, doesn't bat an eye at the name Hoshino until he sees her face.

Doing a full-text search of (a fan translation of) the first 94 chapters, the only characters to mention "Hoshino Ai" are Aqua, Ruby, Ryousuke (the stalker), and the omniscient narrator that can be considered responsible for those little notes at the ends of chapters. Ichigo and Miyako also clearly know, and the information definitely exists somewhere in government records that have likely been accessed by law enforcement.

In chapter 20,

> Kana notes that something about Ruby reminds her of Ai, but has no idea what--when she's inviting her to join the new B-Komachi, under the same agency! If Ai's family name were known, it would be hard not to draw conclusions.

and what's more, in chapter 28,

> when Akane researches Ai in depth in order to flawlessly imitate her, she goes so far as to deduce that she likely had sex during puberty and "maybe met someone nice" at the age of 15, but never noted her family name as something she discovered, and despite doing this as a favor for Aqua doesn't even begin to suspect they could be connected until observing his reaction the next chapter.

In chapter 106,

> after Ai's identity as the twins' mother is revealed:
>
>  Several fans and other background characters are shown reacting to the news. Not one remarks on a shared family name making it obvious in retrospect.
>
>  Furthermore, there are several instances (news broadcasts, Twitter trending) of one or the other twin being referred to by full name, and Ai by given name alone, in the exact same circumstances--implying that even *with* her identity as the mother of the Hoshino twins revealed, nobody's accustomed to referring to her by full name. Hell, that's not even adequate to infer that her own name was Hoshino, since the father's identity as Kamiki Hikaru (as opposed to a hypothetical other Hoshino) has not yet been revealed, and for all the public knows the twins could have changed their names anyways.

In short, changing the twins' names would have been wholly unnecessary for hiding their parentage.